# How to change control template from the view model in WP7?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, mvvm, mvvm-light

Hi basically I've been able to completely seperate my logic into a view model with the exception of one thing. I have a a button and two different templates that can be applied to the button. Basically when audio is playing one template is displayed and when its not the other is displayed. When I was using the code behind this was easy because I had access to the page's Resources and all I had to do was set it accordingly. Now that my code is in the VM though I'm not really sure how to change the template.

The first thought that comes to mind is to maybe send a message to the view to change it when I need to. Is this the only way? I did see that WPF had triggers which looks pretty nice because you don't have to send messages and no code is placed in the code behind. Has anyone found a work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably write a `ValueConverter` that would look at a `public bool IsPlaying` property and transform it to the appropriate template. Then you can databind your `Button` template property to the `IsPlaying` property, using the converter as a translator.

I haven't tried this with templates, but I've used it to great success with `Bitmap` and `Visibility`, so I'm pretty sure it would work here as well.

Here's a [good intro to `ValueConverter`](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/07/30/format-data-in-silverlight-databinding-valueconverter.aspx), if you haven't used one before.

That said, messaging isn't such a horrible solution in this case. Sometimes there is code that just wants to live in the codebehind file. Animation start/stop code is another example that comes to mind.